# Pivot with Month-YY format

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Right now I've got a `cte` that gives me total sales per salesperson per month in a long list. I'm looking to use a `pivot` specifically to have a **column for each month** and **salespeople listed in rows** to more easily display the total sales under each month.

**QUERY:**

```
WITH SalesCTE (Salesperson, Date, TotalSales)
AS
(
SELECT  FirstName + ' ' + LastName AS 'SalesPerson',
        CAST(YEAR(OrderDate) AS nvarchar(10)) + '-' + DateName(MONTH,OrderDate) AS 'Date',
        SUM(TotalDue)
FROM    Person.Person p
JOIN    Sales.SalesOrderHeader s
ON      p.BusinessEntityID = s.SalesPersonID
GROUP BY FirstName, LastName, OrderDate
)


SELECT  SalesPerson, 
        Date, 
        TotalSales
FROM    SalesCTE
ORDER BY Date, SalesPerson
```

**Output at the moment:**

```
David Campbell  2011-December   78223.3018
Garrett Vargas  2011-December   10254.8552
Jillian Carson  2011-December   52586.674
José Saraiva    2011-December   119678.9211
Linda Mitchell  2011-December   6167.1672
Michael Blythe  2011-December   71792.8437
```

**Ideally I want this:**

```
                 December-11  January-12    February-12     ….
David Campbell  78223.3018  73343.3652  77431.389   
Garrett Vargas  10254.8552  176300.293  46954.6224  
Jillian Carson  52586.674   300998.1522 158997.3466 
José Saraiva    119678.9211 180684.8446 182343.3114 
Linda Mitchell  6167.1672   305145.2225 205684.0069
```

There are many other months and salespeople in the list and I've not done anything like this before. Looked up pivots for a few hours but can't get a hang of how they work really.

Comment: Have you attempted to solve this yourself? If so, please post your code along with any errors or the output it produces. That way, users can identify and teach you what was wrong with your attempt rather than give you a solution that you may not understand. There are many examples of [cte's with pivots](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bsql-server%5D%5Bcte%5D+pivot) already on the site, that should be able to assist you with this query if not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insert the table with a new column with original date to a new temp table

```
SELECT *,CAST(DATES+'-01' AS DATE) ORGDATE 
INTO #NEWTABLE
FROM TEMP
```

Now declare variable to get columns for pivot dynamically

```
DECLARE @cols NVARCHAR (MAX)

SELECT @cols = COALESCE (@cols + ',[' + DATENAME(MONTH,ORGDATE)+'-'+RIGHT(CAST(YEAR(ORGDATE) AS
               VARCHAR(4)),2) + ']', 
              '[' + DATENAME(MONTH,ORGDATE)+'-'+RIGHT(CAST(YEAR(ORGDATE) AS VARCHAR(4)),2) + ']')
               FROM    (SELECT DISTINCT ORGDATE,[DATES] FROM #NEWTABLE) PV  
               ORDER BY ORGDATE
```

Now do the pivot

```
DECLARE @query NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @query = 'SELECT * FROM 
             (
                 SELECT NAME, DATENAME(MONTH,ORGDATE)+''-''+RIGHT(CAST(YEAR(ORGDATE)AS VARCHAR(4)),2) logdate, value 
                 FROM #NEWTABLE
             ) x
             PIVOT 
             (
                 SUM(value)
                 FOR logdate IN (' + @cols + ')
            ) p;' 

EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @query
```

- **[SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/11174/1)**

Comment: What's the point of creating the temp table? It seems totally unnecessary.

Comment: Yes. You are right. The OP seems to be a new one to pivot(as he mentioned in question). So I thought it would be be easy for him to read :) @bluefeet♦